# How to get the database value for a Specific field in [HttpPost] edit method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to get the database value in the HttpPost Edit method for a specific field "Quantity" so that i can do some operation on that and than update its value. I am using Entity Framework 6.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditGoogles([Bind(Include = "ProductID,Name,Code,Quantity,etc)] SalesDetail salesdetail)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

     var oldValue =  db.Entry(salesdetail).GetDatabaseValues();
     //here i want to get the Quantity from database 
        int QtyBefore = ???;

     db.Entry(salesdetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
salesdetail.Quantity = //do some operaion with QtyBefore Here and update
     await db.SaveChangesAsync();
     return Json(new { success = true });
    }
    return PartialView("_EditSales", salesdetail);
}
```

Comment: whats your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   Models.YourTableName oldValue = db.YourTableName.Where(q=>q.Quantity==salesdetail.Quantity).Select(p=>p).SingleOrDefault();
   oldValue.Quantity= YourNewValue;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Without actually having all necessary information, here's what I think you'll need:

```
 [HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditGoogles([Bind(Include = "ProductID,Name,Code,Quantity,etc)] SalesDetail salesdetail)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

     var oldValue =  db.Entry(salesdetail).GetDatabaseValues();
     //here i want to get the Quantity from database 
        int QtyBefore = db.Set<SalesDetail>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Quantity == yourquantityid)?.Quantity ;

     db.Entry(salesdetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
salesdetail.Quantity = //do some operaion with QtyBefore Here and update
     await db.SaveChangesAsync();
     return Json(new { success = true });
    }
    return PartialView("_EditSales", salesdetail);
}
```

You can also find heaps of articles about querying the database, such as [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936.aspx) one.

Comment: getting null reference exeption on this solution??

Comment: @Imran I haven't tested it but you get a head start with this. Find what the error is, try to fix it and if you can't figure out you could update your question to give us more details because now it's ballpark for us.